# Enter the_loop() from posts ID

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have looked for this problem and I haven't seen it asked before. I'm sorry if this is a repeated question.

I have done a complex query to my custom database tables, and I have now an array of wordpress posts IDs.

Now I would like to show them with the_loop, but I'm not able to do that. I think it's important to advise you that I'm showing the results by ajax, so all this functionality is in functions.php (maybe this information is irrelevant).

For now I'm getting the posts data with:

```
function imprimirResultados($resultados = null){
    if ($resultados){
        echo '<div class="resultados">';
        foreach ($resultados as $post_id){
            $post = get_post( $post_id[0], ARRAY_A );
            echo '<div class="post" id="post-'.$post['ID'].'">
                  <h2><a href="'.$post['guid'].'" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to '.$post['post_name'].'">
                  '.$post['post_title'].'</a></h2>
                  <div class="entry">
                     '.$post['post_excerpt'].'
                  </div>
                </div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        var_dump($post);
    }else{
        echo    '<h2 class="center">No encontrado</h2>
                <p class="center">Lo sentimos, pero la búsqueda no obtuvo resultados.</p>';
    }
}
```

But it is not a clean method to do that, and I can't use other functionalities that the objects generated by the_loop() already have.

--------------------------------- Edit -------------------------------

I leave here the functions I use:

```
function resultadosLigeros_callback(){

    (...)
    $querystr = cargar_ligeros($marca,$modelo,$combustible,$tipo,$anio); //This function generate a MySQL query
    $resultados = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, ARRAY_N);
    imprimirResultados($resultados, $querystr);//This function is the one I wrote before

    die();
}
```

Comment: `the_loop()` is not a WordPress function...Can you show your function, and what it's hooking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to generate a new [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters), based on the post IDs you have. Specifically, you'll want to use [post__in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters).

For example, since `$resultados` is an array:

```
<?php
    // Fetch the posts
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $resultados ) );

    // The Loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>
```

You can then use functions such as `the_ID()`, etc., directly within your template logic.